# Android - strike out item in list view when touched

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with a list of items (To do), and I was wondering if there is a way to strike out the text, or entire box, when it is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: what have you attempted that has failed so far?

Comment: Googleing. No help.

Also tried to bold listview text to see if that was possible even, that doesnt work...

Comment: You have 12 questions you've asked and you've accepted zero answers. Please go through your list of questions you've asked and accept the correct answers to your questions. People won't be willing to help you if you're not willing to give them credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a click (e.g., in `onListItemClick()` of a `ListActivity`), update your data model to reflect the fact that the to-do item is completed, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`, to trigger the `ListView` to update. In your custom `Adapter`, format the rows as appropriate based upon your data model.